# Can HtmlUnit support to set the content to an online rich text editor?

Tags: javascript, iframe, htmlunit, rte

I am using HtmlUnit to test a web application. It uses an online rich text editor to collect the user input. (The iframe is used without src attribute ). I have to simulate the user input, but I find I have no way to set the content into this iframe.

Can HtmlUnit support this functionality? I googled the web heavily, but found no clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way around is to set it via JavaScript.

```
String jsCode = String.format("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('this is my comment');");
((JavascriptExecutor) drone.getDriver()).executeScript(jsCode);
```

To see that it has set the comment.

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.id("the-iframe-id"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
String value = drone.find(By.tagName("p")).getText();
```